# Symfony2 send a POST request to an external API and parse its XML response?

Tags: php, xml, symfony

How to send a POST request to an external API and parse its XML response?

Normally using only php and xml I would do [something  like](https://gist.github.com/gghhh456/d7ebc23c7c43a3697b74) . But i am not sure how can I to do the same using Symfony.

Also please note that the content inside the xml file is dynamic like "Itemnumber", "quantity" etc

**Moreinfo:**

I am trying to send the xml data to our third party client system(they just work with XML so no JSON response) and parse this XML response and show it to our customers. Well since customer request are dynamic so does the contents inside the .xml file changes every-time. So i need to figure out

1. Load this dynamic .xml file.
2. Make the connection using POST.
3. Read the Parse Xml data which i receive from our client(which can be done easily).

Comment: See that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561816/php-curl-extract-an-xml-response. I think fit your needs. With curl you can do a post request

Comment: but the contents of xml file is dynamic so i also need to figure out the how to pass parameters to xml file

Comment: What do you mean with "dynamic"? Is your question how send and use parameters with the POST request?

Comment: ohh i meant using parameters.. i came across this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480159/using-simplexmlelement-and-symfony2-to-output-xml-file

let you know how it goes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got it working. Its simple

Step 1: Create XMLDocument as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21501784/5600116) OR [See Example1](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php).

```
public function XMLDocument($param){

// Code from the link

return $xmlDoc;
}
```

Step 2: Make The Connection: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18707244/5600116)  and to get XML object

```
public function APiConnection($xmldoc){

 // code from the link

$reponse = curl_exec($ch);
$xmli = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
return $xmli; // returns XML Object
}
```

Step3: Parser the data (which is easy)

Your Action method Should look like:

```
public function DataAction(){

$doc = $this->XMLDocument($param);
$Data = $this->APiConnection($doc);

// parser the xml data
$price= $data->Items['0']->Price;

}
```

I am open for suggestions let me know if you find any mistakes.

I also came across [this document](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#adding-the-content) from Symfony but have not used.